# Windows.Devices.Usb recieve delay

Tags: c#, usb

I made simple C# program that talks to USB device. It works and I can send and receive data correctly.
Problem is that I observe about 100 delay.
I found place where that delay is and I have question how to get rid off it.

That bellow is only part of code:

```
using Windows.Devices.Usb;

UInt32 vid = 0x04D5;
UInt32 pid = 0x0A32;
string aqs    = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);
var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);
UsbDevice device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
DataReader reader = new DataReader(device.DefaultInterface.BulkInPipes[0].InputStream);

Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
await reader.LoadAsync(num);   
stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

stopwatch gives me about 100ms time.  How to make it smaller?  Or maybe different USB lib?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: You probably cannot make it smaller.  Going to a faster Baud Rate will help, but if the delay is in the device response time you cannot change the response time under most cases.  If the device was querying a database than speeding up the database will help.